# PHP and CSS not working fully

Tags: php, html, css

ok i have a problem with my website, my header and footer are affected by the css but my body is not, I've tried editing the values but it does't seem to work, but for some reason if I add a background color to the body class it color changes but the position doesn't. I'm stuck. Please help.
Here's my css:

```
#nav ul 
{
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav li 
{
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10%;
    background-color: red;
}
#nav a:link, a:visited 
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav a:hover, a:active 
{
    background-color: blue;
}

#footer 
{
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 25%
}

.body 
{
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
}
```

Here's my PHP:
header:
    
    
        
        Title

```
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
        var j = Math.floor(8*Math.random());
        var s = new Array();
        s[0]="1";
        s[1]="2";
        s[2]="3";
        s[3]="4";
        s[4]="5";
        s[5]="6";
        s[6]="7";
        s[7]="8";
        s[8]="9";
        k=s[j];
        document.write("<style type='text/css'>body {background-image:url(../images/bg"+k+".jpg);background-attachment:fixed;background-size: 100% 100%;}</style>");
</script>
-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href= "home.php">Refugio</a></li>
<li><a href= "addAccommodation.php">Add accommodation</a></li>
<li><a href= "login.php">Log In/Register</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Home Page:

```
<?php
session_unset();
include ('header.php');
?>
<div class="body">
<b>Refugio</b>
<form action= "results.php" method = "post">
Search Accommodation:
<input type="search" name="accomSearch" required>
</br>
Arrival Date:
<input type="date" name="bday">
</br>   
Departure Date:
<input type="date" name="bday"></br>
<input type="submit" value= "Search">
</form>
</div>
<?php
include ('footer.php');
?>
```

And footer

```
<div id = "footer">
<p>&#169&nbspCompany.<br />
If you have a trouble with our service 
<a href="mailto:ellaine@reo.net">Contact Us
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend making a jsfiddle of it.  This is a CSS issue, not PHP-related.

Comment: Please indent properly so we can read what is going on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set wrapper for your `<div class="body"...` to set some width.

That width will be the base for your body to calculate `25%`

```css
#nav 
{
overflow: hidden;
width:70%;
margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #E1E1E1;

}
#nav ul 
{
list-style-type: none;
width:100%;
text-align: center;
}
#nav li 
{
float: left;
padding-right: 10%;
background-color: red;
}
#nav a:link, a:visited 
{
display: block;
width: 100%;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 4px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav a:hover, a:active 
{
background-color: blue;
}

#footer 
{
  clear:both;
width: 70%;
margin 0 auto;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;

}
.page{
  width:70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
}
.body 
{
  border:solid 1px red;
  margin:5px auto;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

 <div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href= "home.php">Refugio</a></li>
<li><a href= "addAccommodation.php">Add accommodation</a></li>
<li><a href= "login.php">Log In/Register</a></li>
</ul>
</div> 
  
  <div class="page">
<div class="body">
  
<b>Refugio</b>
<form action= "results.php" method = "post">
Search Accommodation:
<input type="search" name="accomSearch" required>
<br />
Arrival Date:
<input type="date" name="bday">
<br />   
Departure Date:
<input type="date" name="bday"><br />
<input type="submit" value= "Search">
</form>
    
</div>
</div>
<div id = "footer">
  <div>
<p>&#169&nbspCompany.<br />
If you have a trouble with our service 
<a href="mailto:ellaine@reo.net">Contact Us</a>
</p>
    </div>
</div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed position of body in css to be absoulte and it worked.
Thanks @Alex for help too, I used bits of your code

Comment: You shouldn't add comments in the answer area. Have you seen/read the Tour?  http://stackoverflow.com/tour. Have a look, you will find a better way to use stackexchange :)